# How can I grab HREF value from a specific DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab the href value from my anchor tag inside of the cellblock class that's nested in multiple divs. How can I grab the href value from the a that I click on? I am unable to edit the HTML to give it a class or ID.

What I'm trying that doesn't work:

```
$("#addtocart .cellblock a").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

For example purposes, feel free to just alert the href value upon click.

**CODE:**

```
<div id="addtocart" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div style="float: right;">
        <div style="width: 120px; float: left; padding: 0 5px; text-align:center;" id="12345">
            <div class="pic">
                <a href="mysite.com"><img border="0" height="100" width="100" src="myimage.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="cellblock" style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="mysite.com">My Product</a>
            </div>
            <div class="cellblock" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <div style="font-weight: bold;" class="sale-red">$9.95</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#addtocart .pic a").prop("href")`  || `$("#addtocart .cellblock a").prop("href")`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var href = $("#addtocart a").attr("href")
```

And using `querySelector`

```
var href = document.querySelector("#addtocart a").getAttribute("href")
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wb7ssynL/

Comment: I realise he asked specifically about using jQuery, but would you add a [plain JavaScript version too](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wb7ssynL/2/)? That way we can maybe prevent duplicates in future arguing "*but that question specifies jQuery...*" :)

Comment: @DavidThomas -- Updated as requested!

Comment: Aaaand it might be worth pointing out the differences between `attr('href')`/`getAttribute('href')` and `prop('href')/`HTMLAnchorElement.href`... ;) (I'm sorry, I hadn't realised the OP specified "*`href` value*", which implies the attribute, but might mean the property too).

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get that value once clicked on, but it doesn't work: Ex: `$("#addtocart .cellblock a").click(function() { alert($(this).attr('href')); });`

Comment: No, both of the options in this answer will - by design - give the `href` attribute-value of the first `<a>` element. Because *in your question* you didn't specify *which `<a>` element you wanted to select*. So, please: update your question (click the "edit" link) to add that information. Also, what precisely do you want? The string from the attribute itself (`"example.com"`) or the property from the element (an absolute URL, presumably `"http://example.com"` in this case)? (Note: because of silly comment restrictions I had to use 'example' in place of 'mysite'.)

Comment: @TreyCopeland -- Your code looks like it should work... what happens?

Comment: @tymeJV it does nothing, but redirect to mysite.com. there are no errors in console.

Comment: So my jsfiddle will work but I can't get it to work on my dev site.